# How to get Rails root_path to redirect to /en/ locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale, rails-i18n

I have an application that is available in EN and DE. Currently, when you enter the website `www.example.com` it does not redirect to default locale. Ideally, I would like root to immediately redirect so I get: `www.example.com/en`.

When I click a root_path link in the app, it goes to the frontpage including the locale `www.example.org/en` as expected.

Question: How do I ensure that users that enters `www.example.com` is redirected to `www.example.com/en` immediately?

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|de/ do
  root 'pages#landingpage'
```

Application controller:

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options(options = {})
  {locale: I18n.locale}
end
```

Comment: Can we see the landingpage action from your pages controller?

Comment: Nothing in there mate - just renders the page.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone who looking answer. In that case you can do

```
root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}"), as: :redirected_root
```

before your locale scope, then you will be redirected to default locale

```
root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}"), as: :redirected_root

scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
 root 'main#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please go through this 
[Internationalization guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization)

Now try this in the routes:

```
scope "(/:locale)" {}
```

and use the `config.default_locale` option in the configuration. you can configure fallbacks for localization.

if you are using cookies to keep track of your locale, you can can skip the `default_url_options`, you will have to keep the unlocalized versions anyways for backward compatibility.